# Can't export stripe API with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, sinon

I have a project using firebase. In `functions/index.js` I have the following code near the top with the imports. This initializes a stripe api instance with the production API key in my firebase config.

```
const stripeProd = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.secret)
```

In my test files I uses Sinon for stubbing and mocking.

At the very bottom of `functions/index.js` I export my express app and the instance of the stripe api shown above:

```
exports.app = functions.runWith(runtimeOptions).https.onRequest(app)

// export these so they can be stubbed in UTs
exports.stripeProd = stripeProd
//.... other exports
```

This export let's me successfully stub out stripe so my UTs don't make API calls.

However, when I try to start this with `firebase serve` I get the following error:

```
 ❮❮❮ firebase serve

// ... stuff
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
⚠  functions: Maximum call stack size exceeded
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

I've found that if I comment out the line exporting the stripe api this error goes away. Why does this happen?

Comment: What does the actual exception and call stack look like?

Comment: no callstack is provided by the firebase tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripeProd = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.key, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27' //this value should be whatever api version you are using
});

//...

exports.stripeProd = stripeProd
```

I hope it helps, I also recommend to import your stripe functions from other files, to work more organized.

Comment: yup, moving the stripe api instance to it's own file solved this problem just like you recommend

Comment: do you mind explaining why using the constructor like this should fix the problem?

Comment: The stripe documentantion have some examples, but I read this repo https://github.com/fireship-io/stripe-payments-js-course/blob/master/server/src/index.ts, basically you have to create an instance of the Stripe Class and export that instance to your proyect, so you can use all the methods that Stripe class has, happy holidays  Paymahn 